# electron-builder doesn't create a release in GitHub when publish is set to always, though there are no errors

Tags: javascript, github, electron, electron-builder, electron-updater

I am trying to publish an electron app to my GitHub repository's releases.

Here is my `package.json`

```
{
  "name": "sample-electron-app",
  "version": "1.0.1",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "electron .",
    "build": "electron-builder build --win --publish never",
    "deploy": "electron-builder build --win --publish always"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "electron": "^13.1.7",
    "electron-builder": "^22.11.7"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "electron-updater": "^4.3.9"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/sriramsridharanvr/sample-electron-app.git"
  }
}
```

When I run the `npm run deploy` script, I expect it to create a release called `v1.0.1` in the GitHub repository, but nothing happens. electron-builder's output doesn't show any error. Here is the console output:

```
• loaded configuration  file=D:\projects\rnd\electron-app-update\prototype-3\sample-electron-app\electron-builder.yml
  • description is missed in the package.json  appPackageFile=D:\projects\rnd\electron-app-update\prototype-3\sample-electron-app\package.json
  • writing effective config  file=dist\builder-effective-config.yaml                               lectron-builder.yml        
  • packaging       platform=win32 arch=x64 electron=13.1.7 appOutDir=dist\win-unpacked             ototype-3\sample-electron-a
  • "token" specified in the github publish options. It should be used only for [setFeedURL](module:electron-updater/out/AppUpdater.AppUpdater+setFeedURL).
  • default Electron icon is used  reason=application icon is not set
  • building        target=nsis file=dist\sample-electron-app Setup 1.0.1.exe archs=x64 oneClick=true perMaelectron-updater/out/AppUpdchine=false
  • building block map  blockMapFile=dist\sample-electron-app Setup 1.0.1.exe.blockmap
  • "token" specified in the github publish options. It should be used only for [setFeedURL](module:chine=falseelectron-updater/out/AppUpdater.AppUpdater+setFeedURL).
  • "token" specified in the github publish options. It should be used only for [setFeedURL](module:electron-updater/out/AppUpdelectron-updater/out/AppUpdater.AppUpdater+setFeedURL).
  • publishing      publisher=Github (owner: sriramsridharanvr, project: sample-electron-app, versioelectron-updater/out/AppUpdn: 1.0.1)
  • uploading       file=sample-electron-app-Setup-1.0.1.exe.blockmap provider=GitHub                      n: 1.0.1)
  • uploading       file=sample-electron-app-Setup-1.0.1.exe provider=GitHub
  • creating GitHub release  reason=release doesn't exist tag=v1.0.1 version=1.0.1
    [====================] 100% 0.0s | sample-electron-app-Setup-1.0.1.exe to GitHub
```

As you can see from the last two lines, it says it created a tag (v1.0.1) and a corresponding release. But my repository has neither created.

Obviously, I'm missing something very trivial. Please help me understand what is going on here.

PS: I was trying to build an auto-updating app, based on [this article](https://medium.com/@johndyer24/creating-and-deploying-an-auto-updating-electron-app-for-mac-and-windows-using-electron-builder-6a3982c0cee6).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Electron-builder will release your app on GitHub as a draft first, then you'll need to manually go in and publish the release.

Take a look in: https://github.com/sriramsridharanvr/sample-electron-app/releases

See if you can see any drafts that have been created.

Comment: Thank you. I was silly enough not to go into the releases page and check!